# How does identityserver4 secure ApiResources?

Tags: c#, identityserver4

In identityserver 4 one places the following code on an apiresource

```
                .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = _platformSettings.IdentityServerUrl;   
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true; 
                    options.ApiName = "myapi";

                });
```

but it seems quite unprotected. Whats to stop some evildoer from creating a console app and using the same code? All they would need to know is the name of my apiresource in this case `myapi`.

Comment: Well, you should be using the ApiSecret to provide a hash for IDS to validate

Comment: Tokens are sent back to a specified endpoint. So if an attacker sent the request from lets say localhost, the token wouldn't be returned to localhost, it is returned to the callback URI defined when registering the app with the provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you think this is insecure? Your `myapi` will only accept tokens issued and signed from the authority of `_platformSettings.IdentityServerUrl`. This is how you need to think about it.

The fact that somebody can create a console app and use the same code is virtually irrelevant, because the clients (your web apps  are consuming api resources, and the clients would be calling endpoints on your hosted api application url, not somebody elses.